# How to extract vendor data using scapy from a probe request

Tags: python, linux, scapy, vendor

So this is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from scapy.all import *
from subprocess import *

call(["clear"])

print "Probe Investigator"
print "-----------------------------------------------------"

intf = raw_input("Enter the Name of the interface to sniff: ")
print ("\n")
clients = []
uni = 0
mach = []

def phandle(p):
    if p.haslayer(Dot11ProbeReq):
        mac = p.addr2
        if p.haslayer(Dot11Elt):
            if p.ID == 0:
                ssid = p.info
                if ssid not in clients and ssid != "":
                    clients.append(ssid)
                    print len(clients),mac+"--Probing-->"+ssid
                    if mac not in mach:
                        mach.append(mac)
                        global uni
                        uni+=1              
                    else:   
                        return

sniff(iface=intf,prn=phandle, store=0)
print ("\n")
print "Unique MACs: ",uni
```

As you can see, I am filtering for probe requests and also filtering to see if the requests aren't broadcast but are for specific SSID's. I analyzed probe requests in *wireshark* to see that such probes also have a tag no *221* in `Dot11ELt` layer which specifies vendor. If I just change the `p.ID == 0` statement to `p.ID == 221` then it should technically give me the vendor info but instead the script just hangs and never moves forward with the rest of the script.

How do I extract vendor info from the packet?

**My python version:** 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) [GCC 4.7.2]
**My linux version:** Distributor ID:Kali
                  Description:Kali GNU/Linux 1.1.0
                  Release:1.1.0
                  Codename:moto
                  **Linux version** 3.18.0-kali3-amd64
                  gcc version 4.7.2 
                  Debian 4.7.2-5) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probe request packet might have several `Dot11Elt` layers and you need to iterate over them until you locate the desired one, as follows:

```
dot11elt = p.getlayer(Dot11Elt)
while dot11elt and dot11elt.ID != 221:
    dot11elt = dot11elt.payload.getlayer(Dot11Elt)
if dot11elt:
    ...  # dot11elt.ID == 221:
```

Comment: Ok so I can reach the information layer now BUT it is encoded in what I though was hex but it isn't. How would I decide it?

Comment: What did you get and what did you expect to get? How did _wireshark_ parse that exact same data?

Comment: Well in wireshark the tag id 221 shows apple or Broadcom as the manufacturer whereas if i look at the same packet in scapy dot11elt with the tag 221 or vendor shows me encoded data.

Comment: _scapy_ won't parse this information element for you. You need to parse it yourself. The _IEEE_ public _OUI_ listing is available at http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess wireshark does it the same way. Thanks a lot for clarifying this for me.